# I don't see fetaured images label in wp-admin panel

Tags: php, wordpress, function, custom-wordpress-pages

I have already tried all the solutions given on the internet. In wordpress documentation shows that I need to add:

```
add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );
add_theme_support( 'custom-logo', array(
'height' => 480,
'width'  => 720,
));
```

To functions.php hooked after 'after_setup_theme'

the whole thing looks like this :

```
function university_features()
{
register_nav_menu('headerMenuLocation', 'Header Menu Location');
register_nav_menu('footerLocationOne', 'Footer Location One');
register_nav_menu('footerLocationTwo', 'Footer Location Two');
add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );
add_theme_support( 'custom-logo', array(
'height' => 480,
'width'  => 720,
));
}
```

add_action('after_setup_theme', 'university_features');

however, I still don't see Featured images label in my wp-admin panel

Comment: I can't tell what you're trying to do, but the featured image and the custom logo are two different theme supports. You need to add `add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );` if you want featured images. Are you trying to add custom image sizes?

Comment: Yes, im trying to add Featured Images tab to my wp-admin panel because i want to add images to my site. I  have already tried to add " 'post-thumbanils' " to my function.php but i still can;t see featured images tab while editing my posts

Comment: There must be something else going on then. `add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );` is the correct line to add support for featured images. Here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails

Comment: If it's not working, try disabling all plugins and checking your theme for typos or a conflict somewhere. I'm afraid we can't help you here without more clues.

Comment: Okay I found a solution to my problem but I don't understand it
as long as there is this in my code :          'supports' => array(''editor'), i dont see featured images tab in my custom posts type while editing. But when i remove this line of code the look of my editor changes and I see the fetured images tab. does anyone know why these two things do not work together?

Comment: However, I still don't see featured images tab in my Pages and Post, I only see it in my custom post types